# Dynamics crm tenant url doesn't work as adal reply url

Tags: dynamics-crm, azureportal, adal.js

I have integrated adal.js in my Dynamics crm custom solution to embed power bi report which works fine but since redirect url need to be set on azure portal app registration so set my tenant url like:

https://myurl.crm6.dynamics.com

but I am getting message like :

> "The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application"

My custom dashboard has been set as default dashboard on tenant. And this custom dashboard contains adal.js and other related js code.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reply url in your tenant needs to exactly match whatever you have set as your reply URL in your app settings/web.config in your code. Have you ensured that these are matching?